# How to put only one thread to sleep?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, multithreading

I want to create two threads in my game. One thread is for timer and other for touch events. Because when I am running my game on iPhone, timer conflicts with touch events and touch events are not reported. It works smooth in simulator but on iPhone or on iPod Touch it's becomes very slow. So I'm using separate threads for touch events and timer.

When I use `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01]` it makes all threads sleep. I mean touch events are also stop to come through. I want to stop the timer thread only.

This is my code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    BOOL Done = NO;
    while (!Done)
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *loopPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(callTapCode) withObject:tapView waitUntilDone:YES];

        //performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(callTapCode) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        [loopPool release];
        Done=YES;
    }

    [pool drain];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a timer, you should probably just use `NSTimer`, because that's simpler and more efficient than creating a thread just to send a "go" event every so often.

edit: As is, you aren't creating a second you are merely stalling the main thread by calling [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01] in a loop. This means your main thread is no longer running the event loop which can cause all kinds of things to no longer work.

Comment: Now my game is running smooth on itouch with thread concept but on iphone its still creating problem to detect touch with timer at time.
I dont why this problem is coming on iphone only

Comment: Are you still using a timer of 0.01? You should leave more time between updates as the human eye cannot see more than 60Hz. The reason why the new iPod touch works but not the iPhone is that it has a faster CPU. On the iPhone, the timer events are being generated faster than they are being consumed.

Comment: My game is totally depend on touch events if it will not get detected because of timer then its of no use. So i use thead concept instead of timer but still some problem ob iphone. I tried everything in it. If u ve other solution then plz tell me

Comment: If you schedule a procedure to run every 1/100 of a second and it takes longer than that to run, the scheduled events will build up in the event queue leaving no room for other events including touch events.

Comment: Whether you schedule those events via NSTimer or performSelectorOnMainThread you will have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];